# What episodes are on the "DVD Collection" release of Pac-Man and the Ghostly Adventures?

Tags: pac-man

On November 4, 2014, a DVD set called ["DVD Collection"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NGAJJMG) was released for the [*Pac-Man and the Ghostly Adventures*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pac-Man_and_the_Ghostly_Adventures) TV series.

This set contains 3 discs and has a total run time of 264 minutes.  Given that each episode is 22 minutes long, that means the DVD set contains 12 episodes.  I have tried Googling and looking at product descriptions on Amazon, Ebay, and other retailers who sell it, but I cannot find a listing of the episodes that it contains.

The company that produces the DVD set is Phase 4 Films, and I found a [product description](http://phase4films.com/Handlers/ReportHandler.ashx?report=FactSheet&projectId=0e2074c9-9d06-e411-a502-d4ae527c3b65&buId=) on their web site.  It does not list the episodes on the DVD set, but it does say the following:

> Join in the adventures of PAC-MAN and his friends in this DVD Collection as they
>   race to see who gets to the Repository first, participate in a Pac-Pong rivalry, and
>   see how much PAC-MAN can eat before he is too full to eat anymore! PAC-MAN
>   DVD Collection is a big, bustling world of action, chills, chases and comedy, starring
>   three unique and winning teenagers who will stop at nothing to protect their
>   friendship, their freedom, and the future! Includes 3 DVDs.

Comparing that description with the [Season 1 and Season 2 episode list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pac-Man_and_the_Ghostly_Adventures_episodes), I have figured out 3 of the episodes:

- "as they race to see who gets to the Repository first": This refers to the "Nobody Knows" episode from Season 1
- "participate in a Pac-Pong rivalry": This refers to the "Pac-Pong Fever" episode from Season 1
- "see how much PAC-MAN can eat before he is too full to eat anymore": This refers to the "All You Can Eat" episode from Season 1

But I don't know what the remaining 9 episodes are.  Season 1 had 26 episodes, so this isn't a set for the full season.  Does anyone have a complete list of the episodes on this DVD set?

Comment: Well, IMO it **is** trivia (and trivial), however in that it appears to not be easily answered, and the poster (obviously) researched it well, +1 anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a better description on [a website](http://www.gohastings.com/product/MOVIE/Pac-Man-and-the-Ghostly-Adventures-DVD-Collection/sku/295157650.uts), which at least specified this is a collection of three previous North America DVD releases, each containing 4 episodes (though without revealing their titles):

> Runtime: 264 Minutes
>
> Number of Discs: 3
>
> **Disc #1 -- Pac-Man and the Ghostly Adventures DVD Collection: Ghost Patrol**
>
> 1. Chapter 1 [:32]
> 2. Chapter 2 [21:30]
> 3. Chapter 3 [:31]
> 4. Chapter 1 [:27]
> 5. Chapter 2 [21:35]
> 6. Chapter 3 [:31]
> 7. Chapter 1 [1:32]
> 8. Chapter 2 [20:30]
> 9. Chapter 3 [:31]
> 10. Chapter 1 [:27]
> 11. Chapter 2 [21:35]
> 12. Chapter 3 [:31]
>
> **Disc #2 -- Pac-Man and the Ghostly Adventures DVD Collection: All You Can Eat!**
>
> 1. Chapter 1 [:30]
> 2. Chapter 2 [21:32]
> 3. Chapter 3 [:30]
> 4. Chapter 1 [:31]
> 5. Chapter 2 [21:31]
> 6. Chapter 3 [:30]
> 7. Chapter 1 [1:27]
> 8. Chapter 2 [20:35]
> 9. Chapter 3 [:30]
> 10. Chapter 1 [:31]
> 11. Chapter 2 [21:32]
> 12. Chapter 3 [:30]
>
> **Disc #3 -- Pac-Man and the Ghostly Adventures DVD Collection: Let The Games Begin!**
>
> 1. Chapter 1 [1:37]
> 2. Chapter 2 [20:25]
> 3. Chapter 3 [:30]
> 4. Chapter 1 [:32]
> 5. Chapter 2 [21:30]
> 6. Chapter 3 [:30]
> 7. Chapter 1 [:31]
> 8. Chapter 2 [21:31]
> 9. Chapter 3 [:30]
> 10. Chapter 1 [1:05]
> 11. Chapter 2 [20:57]
> 12. Chapter 3 [:30]

Looking up each individual DVD revealed that they contain the following season 1 episodes:

**Ghost Patrol**: *Stand By Your Pac-Man*, *PacLantis*, *The Great Chase*, and *Invasion of the Point Heads* (episodes 19, 20, 23 & 26).

**All You Can Eat**: *All You Can Eat*, *President Possessed!*, *Is Zit You or Is Zit Me?*, and *Heebo Skeebo* (episodes 5-7 & 9).

**Let the Games Begin!**: *No Body Knows*, *Seems Like Old Times*, *Betrayus Turns the Heat Up* and *Pac-Pong Fever* (episodes 11-14).

**To sum it up**, this collection contains 12 season 1 episodes: 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 19, 20, 23 & 26, or basically, as [this website](http://www.toonzone.net/forums/toonzone-general-animation-discussion/371111-pac-man-ghostly-adventures-dvd-guide-discussion-thread.html) calls them, Volumes 2, 3 & 4.

Comment: And -100 to a company that releases a product without saying what it contains. :P Thanks

Comment: Definitely. I was shocked at how hard it was to find *any* info on this.

Comment: Can you please add the links you found to your answer?  Thanks!

Comment: Sure, coming right up. Some mobile issues with original website, so putting up a text version.

Comment: Regarding why it's so difficult to find information on this set...  Maybe they want people to double-dip - people who already bought the previous DVDs and are hoping this collection contains all the unreleased episodes.  I'm glad you found the answer.